# Windows LAN IP addresses

Tags: local-area-network

How can I find all the active IP addresses on my LAN and their host names?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? If one of the posts below was a direct answer, you can accept it so that all future readers know the answer and also to reward the person who gave it. If none of the below posts are an answer, you can contribute an answer of your own and accept it to help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your OS:  [NMAP](http://nmap.org/) runs on Linux, Mac & Windows but can be a bit complicated to get started with.  [AngryIP](http://www.angryip.org/w/Home) runs on Windows and is simple to use.

Comment: @ED - I've had issues with AngryIP getting flagged as a virus pretty frequently, dont know if you've seen that. Its one reason I moved away from it.

Comment: Zenmap (nmap gui frontend) does indeed run on Windows.  this is probably the best tool out there for any kind of network scanning.  Be warned, though, Windows boxes are preconfigured to drop ICMP (ping) packets by default.  If you are scanning for Windows machines, make sure you open the local firewall for ICMP traffic, otherwise you won't find them.

Comment: @Ernie, Just because you get a false positive by Security software for angryIP doesn't really speak to how well, it would work in the OPs in enviroment.

Comment: @James - No it doesnt, but its a headache to explain to the EU why the tools you're using get flagged as threats. Its just easier to avoid it and get a different product.

Comment: @Ernie, Yeah I hear that.  Layer 8 problems, huh?

Comment: I have seen it flagged, I've also seen Newt flagged which is another useful tool.  My assumption is anything could get flagged eventually and it's easy enough to work around.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a windows environment you can use [Advanced IP Scanner](http://www.radmin.com/products/utilities/ipscanner.php).
Free, fast, and gives you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

And yet another suggestion for an IP scanner:

- [SoftPerfect Network Scanner](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/)

It can scan for Windows shares, IPs, open ports and etc. Not a bad little freebie.

Answer (score 0):

only Nmap, get the ZenMap GUI with it for noobs. Its really the only tool you should used for scanning LAN networks